# Object and Field Permissions - Apex CRUD Violation

Tags: apex, field-level-security, crud

I have ran the `Apex PMD`, In my result in got the security error with the rule `ApexCRUDViolation`

so I'm checking the field-level read permission  for the selected field before querying  as below.

```
 if(  
            Enrollment__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()  &&
            Schema.SObjectType.Enrollment__c.fields.Id.isAccessible()  && 
            Schema.SObjectType.Enrollment__c.fields.Enrollment_Status__c.isAccessible())
        {
            enrollstatus =  [select  Id, Enrollment__c, (select Id from family__r), 
                              from Enrollment__c WHERE Id=:varid];          
        }
```

but still I'm getting `ApexCRUDViolation` for this SOQL, Do we need to add for Child record too?

I tried by adding like `Schema.SObjectType.Enrollment__c.fields.family__r.Id.isAccessible()`, I'm getting error, Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: I think the use of `stripInaccessible` would make your code way easier.

Comment: You add the check in the same way you have for the parent's object type and fields, so add direct checks you have access to the child object type and the child object type's Id.

Comment: @phil , Means one More If Condition

Answer (score 1):

The schema doesn't support access via the relationship field to permissions. Instead you must directly check the related object's permissions. On the assumption that "Family__r" is a relationship to a custom object called "Family__c" you can check the permissions like:

```
if(  
            Enrollment__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()  &&
            Schema.SObjectType.Enrollment__c.fields.Id.isAccessible()  && 
            Schema.SObjectType.Enrollment__c.fields.Enrollment_Status__c.isAccessible() &&
            Schema.SObjectType.Family__c.isAccessible() &&
            Schema.SObjectType.Family__c.fields.Id.isAccessible())
        {
```